# Setting up a ViewController via url and show it as a popup

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I currently have a method that I use to setup a new ViewController

```
func setRootView(viewController vc: UIViewController){
    UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController = vc
    UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

How can I modify the presentation that the ViewController will show over the other screen like presentation style not modally ?

That is the function that gets called after the button is pressed and the view should change:

```
func moveToNextVC(isLogin: Bool){
    if self.checkNetworkConnection(){
        let vc = HomeVC(nibName: "HomeVC", bundle: nil)
        if isLogin{
            vc.modalPresentationStyle = .automatic
            vc.url = loginLink
            
        }else{
            vc.modalPresentationStyle = .automatic
            vc.url = signupLink
            
        }
        setRootView(viewController: vc)
    }
    else{
        showAlert("Alert!", message: "Please check your internet connection, then try again.")
    }
}
```

Comment: If you just want to bring a view up from the bottom, you can look at `presenting` the view controller. You probably might have to create this animation yourself self if you are looking to replicate a view controller transition. If you notice how the alert pop ups, the overlay is first faded in and the view with the text and button seems to scale from the center.

Comment: I’ve tried that before but that doesn’t work because of that url thing…

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking. What do you mean by a "popup"? A modal dialog that comes up from the bottom of the screen? Do you have a screen-shot of what you are after that you can add to your question?

Comment: Note that you should rarely, if ever, have to mess with the window's root view controller. That is not a good way to change view controllers.

Comment: also what is the `url thing`, it seems like it is just a variable, not sure why that messes up how your view is animated

Comment: Your question says "set up view controller via URL" but you don't explain what the URL has to do with it. It looks like you pas a URL to your destination VC, but it doesn't seem to be relevant to your question. You should clean up your question (and its title) to make it clearer what you want to do and what, exactly, you need help with.

Comment: The view controllers are actually from webkit and just present the url of of a Webapp in the app. It is just a project I’ve not developed myself and need to do that change. And I mean by popular the presentation type that is not morally.

Comment: Maybe a little hard to understand without some visuals is what you mean by `over` the other screen. `Modal` transition actually does what you describe, it brings one view controller over another. Or perhaps you want to look at UINavigationControllers which `pushes` a new view controller `onto` the navigation stack so in is above the previous view controller in hierarchy. The issue in your code is `UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController = vc` - you set your root controller to `vc`. This does not maintain the previous views and resets your view hierarchy.

Comment: Instead of doing this `UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController = vc`, I would do `present(vc, animated: true)`

Comment: Thanks that was the thing I missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [Shawn Frank's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71079048/setting-up-a-viewcontroller-via-url-and-show-it-as-a-popup/71083306#comment125654422_71079048):

> Instead of doing this `UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController = vc`, I would do `present(vc, animated: true)`

This solved the problem.